# I will never see you here again

Tags: meaning-in-context, expressions

I will never see you here again.

Can this be said to mean that I don't want him to come back here (my house) again?

Comment: It might mean that, but more context or a citation would make it clearer.

Comment: "I will never see you here again" is a prediction. If you don't want him to come back you might say "I never want to see you here again".